# How reinstall and not to loose data if Ubuntu installer cannot detect my old Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

my update from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 was recently interrupted by power failure so I decided to reinstall it. I run the install from usb but when I choose reinstal ubuntu error window appear:

"The parititon table farmat in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition should be marked for use as an EFI boot partition and should be at least 35 MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition mounted on /boot."

So I went to repair this this problem. Obviously not very wisely. When I looked on the partitions there was sda2 mounted on /boot efi for use of ntfs. I took 60 MB from large partition used by swap and make it as a new partition used as EFI boot partition. However: This message appeared:

"Two file systems are assigned the same mount point (/boot/efi): SCI1(0,0,0) partition 2(sda) and SCI1 (0,0,0), partition 9(sda)". Where partition 9 is the newly created. So I left it as a free space and carried on with the instalation ignoring the first error message.

But in the middle of setting up the location, keyboard layout etc. another error appeared  about failure at partition 2 (i know it would be helpful if I knew what it was but I dont). And the installation stoped.

Now when I try to install again from the usb it said that there is no operation system on my computer (although windows can be booted by changing the boot priority in bios). the half borken 13.10 cannot be booted at all.

But my question is: Is there now a way how to reinstall ubuntu without loss of data? Even the installer cannot detect any OS?

I know I did many wrong things. I just like Ubuntu so much, even though I am not good in computers. I wold appreciate any help.

Thanks, Alice

Comment: It will be much easier to answer your question if you edit the output of the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) into your question.

Comment: @searchfgold6789, I don't know about Alice, but I wouldn't have a idea how to get the output you want, maybe you can give a short tutorial or find one?

Comment: There are [instructions on the SourcForge page](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/) (there's a link to them on the page I provided a link to).

Comment: I missed it, but it is nice to have the direct link in the comment I think ;)

Comment: Always backup your home folder **before** an upgrade.